# Compare two dates by retaining formats

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to add hours to date and making comparisons using after function but formats are getting changed.

```
              Date compDate= new Date("2023-07-14");
              Date newDate = new Date("2023-07-13 01:22:14.077");
              SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 
                                                                   HH:mm:ss.SSS");
              Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
              cal.setTime(newDate );
              cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,Integer.parseInt("12"));
              newDate= cal.getTime(); //Returns for example(in this format) Tue Jul 2023 
              12:00:00
              String dateStr = dateFormat.format(newDate);
              Date jobDate = dateFormat.parse(dateStr);
              compDate.after(jobDate);
```

Expectations:
Retain the  date in the format(yyyy-MM-dd                                   HH:mm:ss.SSS) after adding 12 hours also which I am not able to get it

Comment: This code doesn't run and I can't make sense of the question.

Comment: Format is irrelevant, `compDate.after(newDate);` should be more then enough.  You should also be making use of the new `java.time.*` APIs

Comment: You should only worry about format when you dipslay a date or time. During comparison, the format doesn't matter. Formatting a date object and then parsing it is again is pointless. Just use the `newDate` object directly.

Comment: In _Java 20_ those _Date_ constructors are deprecated; plus I get an _IllegalArgumentException_ during the parse.

Comment: @Reilas FYI, the constructors have been deprecated since Java 1.1 , wish they'd deprecate it and `Calendar` as well

Comment: @MadProgrammer, unbelievable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatting is irrelevant.  `Date`, like most date/time classes `Date` is a container for the amount of time which has passed since a given point in time (in this case, the Unix Epoch).

The result of `Date#toString` should only be used for debug purposes and it's result could change depending on localisation and time zone.

You should also beware that `Date` DOES NOT carry any formatting information, again, it's output should purely be considered for debugging only, in almost all other cases, use a formatter instead, that's why they exist.

If we take some time to "fix" your code (so it will run) and output the values...

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

Date compDate = dateFormat.parse("2023-07-14 01:22:14.077");
Date newDate = dateFormat.parse("2023-07-13 01:22:14.077");

System.out.println("   compDate = " + dateFormat.format(compDate) + " // Formatted");
System.out.println("   compDate = " + compDate);
System.out.println("    newDate = " + dateFormat.format(newDate) + " // Formatted");
System.out.println("    newDate = " + newDate);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(newDate);
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
newDate = cal.getTime();

System.out.println("new newDate = " + dateFormat.format(newDate) + " // Formatted");
System.out.println("new newDate = " + newDate);

System.out.println("Compare = " + compDate.after(newDate));
```

We end up with something like...

```
   compDate = 2023-07-14 01:22:14.077 // Formatted
   compDate = Fri Jul 14 01:22:14 AEST 2023
    newDate = 2023-07-13 01:22:14.077 // Formatted
    newDate = Thu Jul 13 01:22:14 AEST 2023
new newDate = 2023-07-13 13:22:14.077 // Formatted
new newDate = Thu Jul 13 13:22:14 AEST 2023
Compare = true
```

As you can clearly see, the value of `Date` doesn't change, but we can affect the output through the formatter.

## Modern approach...

Let's update the code to remove the reliance on deprecated functionality and make use of the newer `java.time.*` APIs, which you should be using instead.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
LocalDateTime compDate = LocalDateTime.parse(
        "2023-07-14 01:22:14.077",
        formatter
);
LocalDateTime newDate = LocalDateTime.parse(
        "2023-07-13 01:22:14.077",
        formatter
);

System.out.println("compDate = " + compDate);
System.out.println("compDate = " + formatter.format(compDate) + " // Formatted");
System.out.println(" newDate = " + newDate);
System.out.println(" newDate = " + formatter.format(newDate) + " // Formatted");

newDate = newDate.plusHours(12);

System.out.println(" newDate = " + newDate);
System.out.println(" newDate = " + formatter.format(newDate) + " // Formatted");

System.out.println("Compare = " + compDate.isAfter(newDate));
```

Which outputs...

```
compDate = 2023-07-14T01:22:14.077
compDate = 2023-07-14 01:22:14.077 // Formatted
 newDate = 2023-07-13T01:22:14.077
 newDate = 2023-07-13 01:22:14.077 // Formatted
 newDate = 2023-07-13T13:22:14.077
 newDate = 2023-07-13 13:22:14.077 // Formatted
Compare = true
```

Again, the format is irrelevant.  Get your values from `String` (and make use of ISO standard formats to do it) to `LocalDate`/`LocalDateTime` (or the `Zoned` variants) and manipulate them as needed, you only need care about the format when it needs to be presented to the user.